# what is the equation for the path of the water if the maximum height of the water must be 4 feet

Tags: quadratics

We are only told that the maximum height is 4 feet for the water fountain so we know that the vertex is (0,4).  We think we would use the formula y=a(x-h)^2-k, but we do not know what to put in for x or y.

Comment: Can you please include the **complete** context of the problem along with your efforts..

Comment: What is h and what is k?